# Не сортирует листу

Tags: java

```
public class BubbleSort<Pojazd> implements ListSorter<Pojazd>{
    private final Comparator<Pojazd> _comarator;

public BubbleSort(Comparator<Pojazd> comparator){
    _comarator = comparator;   }

@Override
public ArrayList<Pojazd> sort(ArrayList<Pojazd> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    for (int pass = 1; pass<size; pass++){
        for (int left = 0; left < (size-pass); left++ ){
            int right = left+1;
            if (_comarator.compare(list.get(left), list.get(right))>0)
                swap(list,left,right);
        }
    }


    return null;
}

public void swap(ArrayList<Pojazd> list, int left, int right){
    Pojazd temp = list.get(left);
    list.set(left,list.get(right));
    list.set(right, temp);

}}



public class Main {
public static void main(String [] args){

ArrayList<Pojazd> arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add(new Pojazd("Jeep"));
    arrayList.add(new Pojazd("Volkswagen"));
    arrayList.add(new Pojazd("Ford"));
    arrayList.add(new Pojazd("Mercedes"));
    arrayList.add(new Pojazd("Audi"));
    arrayList.add(new Pojazd("Nissan"));
    System.out.println(arrayList);



BubbleSort bubbleSort = new BubbleSort(new Comparator<Pojazd>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Pojazd left, Pojazd right) {
           return 0;
       }
   });

bubbleSort.sort(arrayList);
    System.out.println(arrayList);


}
```

Вывод

```
[Nazwa: Jeep, Nazwa: Volkswagen, Nazwa: Ford, Nazwa: Mercedes, Nazwa: Audi, Nazwa: Nissan]
[Nazwa: Jeep, Nazwa: Volkswagen, Nazwa: Ford, Nazwa: Mercedes, Nazwa: Audi, Nazwa: Nissan]
```

Имлементирует :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface ListSorter<T> {
    public ArrayList<T> sort(ArrayList<T> list);
}
```

Тип

```
public class Pojazd {

private String nazwa;

public Pojazd(String n) {
    this.nazwa = n;
}

public String getName() {
    return nazwa;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Nazwa: " + this.nazwa ;
}

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что вставлять в конструктор (там где Comparator), и как протестить время работы алгоритма, и почему он не сортирует

Comment: А что содержит класс Pojazd(лучше его добавить)? Вы хотите отсортировать просто по алфавиту сами названия (Volkswagen) или как-то иначае?

Comment: @Дмитрий, От самого большого слова до самого маленького. Pojazd это отдельный класс где я могу задать данные как название машины , цвет, возраст и т.д А тут задаю его как тип

Comment: Ну у вас же компаратор, который вы передаете в конструктор класса `BubbleSort`, ничего не делает -- всегда возвращает `0`, так что сортировщик считает, что все объекты равны друг другу и ничего не переставляет. А вообще для получения корректного ответа следует приводить код всех используемых классов (убрав из них всё, не относящееся к вопросу) -- никому не известно, что это за `ListSorter` и что за `Pojazd`

Comment: Отлично, покажите этот класс - Pojazd

Comment: @Дмитрий , дал всю информацию

Comment: @m.vokhm, так что именно в моем случаи компаратор должен возвращать?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша сортировка не работает, потому что компаратор всегда возвращает 0.

Чтобы список отсортировался возвращайте, например, разность длин названий:

```
return left.getName().length() - right.getName().length();
```

Время работы алгоритма можно замерить путём фиксации времени до и после вызова `bubbleSort.sort(arrayList);`

То есть:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
bubbleSort.sort(arrayList);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(end - start);
```

Метод `System.currentTimeMillis()` возвращает время в миллисекундах, если нужно время в наносекундах, то используйте `System.nanoTime()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pojazd {

    private String name;

    public Pojazd(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nazwa: " + this.name;
    }

    public static List<Pojazd> bubbleSort(List<Pojazd> pojazds) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pojazds.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < pojazds.size() - i - 1; j++) {
                if (pojazds.get(j).getName().length() > pojazds.get(j + 1).getName().length()) {
                    Pojazd temp = pojazds.get(j);
                    pojazds.set(j, pojazds.get(j + 1));
                    pojazds.set(j + 1, temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return pojazds;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Pojazd> pojazds = new ArrayList<>();
        pojazds.add(new Pojazd("Jeep"));
        pojazds.add(new Pojazd("Volkswagen"));
        pojazds.add(new Pojazd("Ford"));
        pojazds.add(new Pojazd("Mercedes"));
        pojazds.add(new Pojazd("Audi"));
        pojazds.add(new Pojazd("Nissan"));

        System.out.println(Pojazd.bubbleSort(pojazds));

    }

}
```

Comment: Проблема в том что нужно именно алгоритмом Bubble sort

Comment: Не хочу даже спрашивать, зачем вы изобретаете велосипед, но код исправил...