# Как реализовать сортировку пузырьком архитектурой Флинна (SIMD) на Java?

Tags: java

У меня есть задача реализовать сортировку пузырьком архитектурой Флинна а именно Simd. В Simd сказано, что это должны быть векторные операции, но никаких примеров на Java не смог найти. Понятия не имею как это сделать.

> SIMD (single instruction stream / multiple data stream) - одиночный
>   поток команд и множественный поток данных. В архитектурах подобного
>   рода сохраняется один поток команд, включающий, в отличие от
>   предыдущего класса, векторные команды. Это позволяет выполнять одну
>   арифметическую операцию сразу над многими данными - элементами
>   вектора. Способ выполнения векторных операций не оговаривается,
>   поэтому обработка элементов вектора может производится либо
>   процессорной матрицей, как в ILLIAC IV, либо с помощью конвейера, как,
>   например, в машине CRAY-1.

Comment: попробуйте пользоваться поиском. я на этой неделе отвечал на аналогичный вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963701/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83?noredirect=1#comment1613889_963701

Comment: @Дмитрий Ваш ответ использует SIMD инструкции? В Java  вообще можно заставить JVM использовать их или игнорировать?

Comment: Java Vector API ещё находится в разработке, а других способов явно работать с SIMD из Java нет, на сколько мне известно.

Comment: @MBo по умолчанию HotSpot пытается использовать SIMD, когда это возможно. Отключить это можно ключом `-XX:-UseSuperWord`.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev Да, подобной ситуации я и ожидал, поэтому насторожился

Comment: @Дмитрий попробуйте внимательнее прочитать задачу...SIMD

Comment: Oracle и Intel работают над этим: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3297748/oracle-and-intel-seek-to-build-a-java-api-for-simd-support.html

Answer (score 0):

В Java-коде сейчас нет возможности явно указать компилятору место, где нужно использовать инструкции SIMD ([JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) в расчет не берется), т.к. в [байткод-инструкциях](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) JVM нет такой команды. Однако, т.к. JVM перегоняет байткод в нативный, ***при этом анализируя его***, то можно посоветовать JVM делать эту перегонку по-возможности используя инструкции SIMD. Это делается при помощи опции `-XX:+UseSuperWord`

Answer (score 0):

В случае вычислений с использованием целочисленный типов JVM может преобразовать операции над значениями хранящихся в массивах в SIMD инструкции. Например такой код:

```
int[] x = ...
int[] y = ...
int[] z = ...

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    z[i] = x[i] * y[i];
}
```

может быть развернут в SIMD:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   x3  |   x2  |   x1  |   x0  | xmm0
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    *       *       *       *
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   y3  |   y2  |   y1  |   y0  | xmm1
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
    =       =       =       =
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   z3  |   z2  |   z1  |   z0  | xmm0
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Я не писал числодробилок и темой знаком плохо, но ранее мне попадались статьи вроде этой http://prestodb.rocks/code/simd/

В статье, помимо тестов производительности, приведен пример того, как можно убедится что JVM в момент исполнения генерирует нужный ассемблер, для этого есть ключ: `-XX:CompileCommand=print,*BenchmarkSIMDBlog.increment` где BenchmarkSIMDBlog эти имя класса из примера по ссылке, то есть его нужно будет поменять на свой.